# Using Extensions in Calendar Events

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, azure-ad-graph-api

Im building a time report app using Microsoft Graph to read/write to the users Outlook Calendars and another connector to read/write to an ERP System. So I need some meta data in the calendar events like customer number, project number etc. 
I'd rather put that in to the events using open extensions but there are some issues with that, could need a nudge in the right direction

The problems with open extensions: 
When copying a calendar event from another client than a PC, e.g a Mac the Open Extensions does not get copied to the new event.

Is the best approach here to just put that as text in the body of the event instead, with the risk of that the users can freely change and destroy. 
Or is there a way to have non-PC outlook clients copy the extension data?

Ideas or suggestions much appreciated. Thanks.